# If statement at namespace scope?

Tags: c++, c++20

In the following C++ program:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

extern "C" int printf(const char*,...);

std::pair<double, double> sincos(double s) {
  return {std::sin(s), std::cos(s)};
}

void g(double a, double b) {
   printf("sin(a)=%f; cos(b)=%f\n", a, b);
}

auto [a,b] = sincos(30);

if (a < b)   // <---- HERE
  g(a,b);

int main() {

}
```

An if statement appears at namespace scope.

This seems to not be allowed by the standard C++ grammar (or is it?), but clang accepts it:

https://godbolt.org/z/ET5Gv8Ebf

Is this an extension?  If so, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Why did you add the [`-fincremental-extensions`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fincremental-extensions) flag? Do you know what it does?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I didn't create the godbolt example and I didn't notice the flag.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I just hope I didn't come around as too rude. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not at all.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not legal C++. Seems like a clang extension that's enabled by the flags you have added (`-Xclang -fincremental-extensions`)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Right, it's the `-fincremental-extensions`.  See link above @Someprogrammerdude posted.